# Intellisense in ev3 micropython not working

Tags: intellisense, micropython, lego-mindstorms, lego-mindstorms-ev3

I'm starting now to program in EV3 Micropython, and I can't get the Intellisense to work. How can I solve this problem? I've tried everything. If someone could help me, it would mean a lot to me... Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already fixed it, but a lot of people may be in the same situation, so here is how I fixed:

1- Select python interpreter version 3.9.6
2- Disable and enable the python extension

You are welcome.